# Windows Azure and a third-party Windows Service

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

I am developing a website that I intend to run within Windows Azure using a single Web Role. The site will make use of the Sphinx Search engine which will need to run as a Windows Service. So, my question is this...is it possible to install the Sphinx Search Windows Service inside of a Web Role.

From my initial research into Azure I am thinking "yes" for the reason that the Web Role is a VM running IIS. Therefore I should be able to remote in, install the service, and it should work. :)

Does this sound right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading your answers, and thinking about it a bit more, I think dropping the idea of installing a service would be the best course of action. I've been looking at the API for Lucene.NET (this may be the same for Sphinx) and it's possible to encapsulate the writing/managing of indexes, etc, within in code and therefore no need for a service.

For the Azure, there is a library for managing index files using both local and Azure storage which could be of use. Scenarios I've read about show that it's then possible to have a Web Role that will process HTTP requests and perform the searches and a Worker Role to accept DB changes via a queue and have it write them to the indexes.

Comment: Do you mean Service as in Windows Service or service as in WCF service.  If WCF service you can host in IIS via a Web Role.  Don't know about Sphinx but I am pretty sure you can host Lucene.NET as WCF service.  And I am pretty sure you could host it as a Worker Role.  If you scale out to multiple sites then clearly the search engine will need to synchronize.

Answer (score 1):

Installing software via RDP is not a viable solution with Web/Worker role instances, as these changes won't persist. You need to install it either from a startup script or from `OnStart()`. Since you want to install as a service, that would imply startup script, since it would need elevated permissions. Note: The installer must support unattended mode, where all parameters are specified via command line with no human interaction.

What about scalability? If you have more than one instance of your web role running, can sphinx run across two instances? From what I read, it supports ODBC-compliant databases, and you might be able to use it against Windows Azure SQL Database. If that's the case, can two sphinx engines run on two different machines accessing the same data store? If so, this sounds like a viable solution.

If installation cannot be automated, or you need something additional like MySQL, you may want to consider placing the sphinx search engine inside a Virtual Machine (new in June 2012). Now you can spin up a Windows 2008 Server, RDP into it, configure it exactly how you want it.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking yes, you *could* do that. However this makes the assumption that you would be running on one VM instance and also that the instance would never need restarting.

You should consider looking at Azure worker roles for any functionality that would normally exist as a windows service.

Comment: Unforunately this is not possible as the Windows Service is a 3rd party service that would need installing in Azure. I am hoping that it will be possible to add some kind of install script to the Web Role, so if the role was moved to another VM, then the script would install the Windows Service.

Comment: I would think that as soon as the VM was moved/restarted you may loose your current index/catalogues and it would need to start re-indexing your content. You could try using Azure storage but then this would require an Azure-specific implementation of Sphinx.

Comment: I see what your saying. So if I wrote anything to a local file storage (not azure storage) with the web role there is no way to replicate the data across to the new VM?

Comment: See [here](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/Post/Windows-Azure-Local-File-Storage-How-To-Guide-and-Warnings.aspx) for some guidance

Comment: Clarification on the answer: Worker roles offer no advantage over web roles. They're both Windows Server, but Web roles have IIS activated.